# C# Out of Memory Exception Store File as Byte Array in DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, stream, out-of-memory

I'm having issues with an "out of memory" exception that I can't reproduce, but a build server that runs unit tests hits every time. Running the unit tests on my machine doesn't cause the exception. The changes made were because the original code was having an odd issue with large PDF's in the passed in stream. If you have an idea of why the original code had issues with the large PDF's or why the new code would cause an "out of memory" exception then let me know.

Original Code:

```
// stream is a valid Stream and parentKey is a valid int
// Reset the stream position
stream.Position = 0;
int sequenceNumber = 0;
int StreamReadSize = short.MaxValue;
byte[] buffer = new byte[StreamReadSize]; 
MemoryStream outStream = null;
try
{
    long previousStreamPosition = 0;
    long DataBlockSize  = 52428800;
    int read;
    while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        if (outStream == null)
            outStream = new MemoryStream(new byte[System.Math.Min(stream.Length - previousStreamPosition, DataBlockSize)]);

        previousStreamPosition = stream.Position;
        outStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        if (outStream.Position <= (DataBlockSize - StreamReadSize) && stream.Position < stream.Length)
            continue;

        var dataRow = dataSet.Tables["table_name"].NewRow();
        dataRow["parent_key"] = parentKey;
        dataRow["key"] = FuncThatReturnsNextAvailableKey();
        dataRow["sequence_number"] = ++sequenceNumber;
        // Reset the position and Zip up the data
        outStream.Position = 0;

        dataRow["data_segment"] = FuncThatZipsAStreamToByteArray(outStream);

        dataSet.Tables["table_name"].Rows.Add(dataRow);

        outStream.Flush();
        outStream.Dispose();
        outStream = null;
    }
}
finally
{
    if (outStream != null)
        outStream.Dispose();
}
```

New Code:

```
// stream is a valid Stream and parentKey is a valid int
// Reset the stream position and create the variables needed for saving the file data
stream.Position = 0;
int sequenceNumber = 0;
int bytesRead;
int DataBlockSize = 52428800;
byte[] buffer = new byte[DataBlockSize];
while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, DataBlockSize)) > 0)
{
    sequenceNumber++;

    // Create and initialize the row
    var dataRow = dataSet.Tables["table_name"].NewRow();
    dataRow["parent_key"] = parentKey;
    dataRow["key"] = FuncThatReturnsNextAvailableKey(); ;
    dataRow["sequence_number"] = sequenceNumber;

    // If the stream reads in less data than the size of the buffer then create an appropriately sized version of the buffer
    // that will only hold the data that was read in
    if (bytesRead != DataBlockSize)
    {
        var shrunkBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
        Array.Copy(buffer, shrunkBuffer, bytesRead);
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(shrunkBuffer))
            dataRow["data_segment"] = FuncThatZipsAStreamToByteArray(memoryStream);
    }
    else
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            dataRow["data_segment"] = FuncThatZipsAStreamToByteArray(memoryStream);
    }

    // Add the finished row
    dataSet.Tables["table_name"].Rows.Add(dataRow);
}
```

Comment: Does your build server have less (available) memory to run these unit tests than your local machine?  Is it possibly running (unit tests for) other builds at the same time it is running these unit tests?

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense that two different environments might generate a different result. it could be that your build server has less memory than your personal coding environment.

It could be that you are keeping your byte arrays in memory via:

```
dataRow["data_segment"] = FuncThatZipsAStreamToByteArray(memoryStream);
```

Your are disposing the output stream, but i am assuming your data row stays in memory, hence your are keeping a reference to that byte array. it could be so that multiple PDFs reach the maximum amount of allocation your process can allocate for itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class memorytributary

From sources at https://gist.github.com/bittercoder/3588074

```
        using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (MemoryTributary memT = new MemoryTributary())
            {

                memT.ReadFrom(stream, stream.Length);
                return memT.ToArray();
            }
        }
```